# Can StreamSocketListener host SignalR?

Tags: signalr, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Universal Windows Platform app running on Windows IoT (ARM) that starts up a web server via StreamSocketListener.  I'd like to be able to push content to web browsers via SignalR.  There's an enormous number of SignalR nuget packages, but it appears that none of them will work in UWP.  Is this correct?  If so what is my best option for pushing content down to browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modern web browsers, SignalR would use Web Sockets for bidirectional communication with the client.  You can see if your client browser will support Web Sockets at [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).

There is an open source project whose specific goal is providing a Web Socket server in a UWP app.  I don't have first-hand experience with the project and it's <1.0 but it mentions compatibility with Windows 10 IoT Core so it may be worth exploring.  You can find the project on NuGet here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IotWeb/

On the client, you can then use the [WebSocket object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) in JavaScript to open a connection with your server.